# JAVA_HOME Errors

Tags: java, windows

I know there are lots of questions and answers about this but none of them are working. I am on a Windows 7 Computer.

I have set my JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables but I keep on getting errors. I have set it to

```
     "C:\Program Files\java\jdkxxx\"
```

(xxx = Java Version) I have tried setting it without quotes and it still doesn't work.
I get the error

```
    ERROR: JAVA_HOME variable is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\java\java1.7.0_21\ Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

Comment: Did you checked the paths and variable name are match exactly and pointing to correct path?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right directory name? On my machine, it's `C:\Program Files\java\jdkxxx`. I don't think the JDK normally installs itself in a directory with the name pattern you are using. (But perhaps you customized the installation.)

Comment: I think your path ist wrong. I think it must be somthing like `C:\Program Files\java\jre1.7.0_21\` or `C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_21\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the trailing backslash **and remove the quotes**

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\java1.7.0_21
```

Comment: I am reinstalling as there is probly some issu with the Install

Comment: No.  The problem with the quotes.  Change it to `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\java1.7.0_21`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Navigate to C:/Program Files/Java
Look for any JDK folders and find the last version if you don't have any of them then Download and install from Java official website HERE

**2.** On your Desktop, right-click on My Computer and open Properties
From the left side choose Advanced system settings

**3.** At the bottom of the window, press the Environment variables button.
Now we got to add the variable in the both: User and System variable boxes.

**4.** Click New button at the User variables box and write:
Variable name: JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk-folders-name
NOTE: use Progra~1 for Windows x64 and Progra~2 for Windows x32
Then press OK

**5.** Do the same for the System variables box

**6.** Press Ok till you close all the windows and run again your Soft.

Or check this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47K3gBla76o